# Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly for DCM to raw file

Tags: numpy, python-3.5, dicom, pydicom

I learn how to convert DCM file to Raw file .Got the code from Git Hub:
https://github.com/xiasun/dicom2raw/blob/master/dicom2raw.py
And it got a error"Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly" on the line
"allInOne += dataset.PixelData"
I try to use "encode("utf-8")",but it make allInOne to be empty.
By the way ,Is there any code to generate the .mhd file corresponding to the .raw file?

```
import dicom  
import os  
import numpy  
import sys  
dicomPath = "C:/DataLuna16pen/dcmdata/"
lstFilesDCM = []  # create an empty list
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(dicomPath):  
    allInOne = ""
    print(subdirList)
    i=0
    for filename in fileList:
        i+=1
        if "".join(filename).endswith((".dcm", ".DCM")): 
            path = dicomPath + "".join(filename)
            dataset = dicom.read_file(path)
            for n,val in enumerate(dataset.pixel_array.flat): 
                dataset.pixel_array.flat[n] = val / 60
                if val < 0:
                    dataset.pixel_array.flat[n] = 0

            dataset.PixelData = numpy.uint8(dataset.pixel_array).tostring() 
            allInOne += dataset.PixelData        
            print ("slice " + "".join(filename) + " done ",end=" ")
            print (i)

    newFile = open("./all_in_one.raw", "wb")
    newFile.write(allInOne)
    newFile.close()
    print ("RAW file generated")
```

Comment: Why are you trying to write the pixel data into a string?

Comment: I try run the code from reference link. He had comment ## convert int16 to int8.## I do not fully understand the code . my purpose is to convert one patient`s Dicom slices to raw file and mhd file. Thanks you ~

Answer (score 1):

There are several things:

- PyDicom still doesn't read compressed DICOMs properly (loseless jpeg). You should check Transfer Syntax of the files to check if this is the case. As a workaround you can use GDCM tool `dcmdjpeg`
- you should not convert byte array into string (`np.array.tostring` returns in fact the  [array of bytes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tostring.html))
- for writing mha files, take a look at [MedPy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MedPy). You can also use ITK directly. There is python wrapper and SimpleITK - some kind lightweight modification of ITK